# Activate tool strip click event from another form

Tags: c#, .net, toolstrip

I need to send a click event to `refreshToolStripMenuItem` from another form. Here is what I have, for some reason it doesn't work. Help please.

Menu item click:

```
public void refreshToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    noteslist.Items.Clear();
    idlist.Items.Clear();
    setnotes();
}
```

Code used to send event:

```
frmnotes notes = new frmnotes();
notes.refreshToolStripMenuItem_Click(this, e);
this.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont call the event itself.
It's bad code.
Put the create an own protected void updateMyList() Method.

```
    internal void updateMyList()
    {
         noteslist.Items.Clear();
         idlist.Items.Clear();
         setnotes();
    }
```

Then call the update-method from within your event.

```
    private void refreshToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updateMyList();
    }
```

Then simply call the update-method from your form:

```
       frmnotes notes = new frmnotes();
       notes.updateMyList();
       this.Close();
```

Btw.: Set the modifier of your Click events i.e. refreshToolStripMenuItem_Click to private.
You never should call them from outside the form. 
Take a look at the MVC pattern for more info. It really helps.

Comment: Tis just says that updatemylist is inaccessible due to its protection level so I changed protected to public but then when I run it it doesn't run the updateMyList..

Comment: Lets say you have two forms, as I suppose, it's your case, too.
Form1 is called `MainForm` and Form2 is called `frmnotes`.
In your frmnotes-Class you find:
- `refreshToolStripMenuItem_Click(..)`
- `updateMyList()`
In your MainForm you have to do something like this:
`frmnotes notes = new frmnotes();
       notes.updateMyList();
       this.Close(); `
This has to work, otherwise the code itself is wrong.
I don't understand why you have to use public either. 
Maybe you can upload your project, so I can have a look at it.

Comment: And try to set the modifier to internal.